# Minecraft Spigot: Null pointer Error while registering a command

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have a plugin but I've been having an issue registering a command. the command is setup in the onEnable along with in the plugin.yml. any ideas on what could be wrong?

**Main Class**

```java
public void onEnable() {
        //////
        this.getCommand("wsmain").setExecutor(new wsmain());
}
```

**Plugin.yml**

```
name: [Redacted]
version: ${project.version}
author: [Redacted]
main: [Redacted]

commands:
  wsmain:
    description: [Redacted]
    usage: /<command>
    permission: ws.main

api-version: 1.13

loadbefore: [FastAsyncWorldEdit, WorldEdit, BuildersUtilities]
```

**StackTrace**

> [14:57:23 INFO]: [WorldSystem] Enabling WorldSystem v2.4.10
> [14:57:23 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling WorldSystem v2.4.10 (Is it up >to date?)
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at de.butzlabben.world.WorldSystem.onEnable(WorldSystem.java:103) ~>>>[?:?]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263)
> [patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at >org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:380>) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at >org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:48>3) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:500) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:414) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:209) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:941) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:177) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
> [14:57:23 INFO]: [WorldSystem] Disabling WorldSystem v2.4.10
> [14:57:23 ERROR]: Error occurred while disabling WorldSystem v2.4.10 (Is it up to date?)
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
> at de.butzlabben.world.WorldSystem.onDisable(WorldSystem.java:212) ~[?:?]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:265) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.disablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:415) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:516) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:384) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:483) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:500) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:414) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:209) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:941) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:177) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-135]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
> at de.butzlabben.world.config.PluginConfig.getConfig(PluginConfig.java:95) ~[?:?]
> at de.butzlabben.world.config.PluginConfig.getDatabaseType(PluginConfig.java:212) ~[?:?]
> at de.butzlabben.world.util.database.DatabaseProvider.(DatabaseProvider.java:14) ~[?:?]
> at de.butzlabben.world.util.database.DatabaseProvider.(DatabaseProvider.java:8) ~[?:?]
> ... 12 more

Comment: Could we get the stack trace? Please also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error was Spigot Gradlew Doesn't use the traditional Plugin.yml

https://github.com/spigradle/spigradle/blob/master/docs/spigot_plugin.md#usage

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it by deliting the "this." before getCommand("...").?

Comment: Consider rephrasing your Answer to sound less like a question.

Answer (score 0):

[?:1.8.0_231] [14:57:23 INFO]: [WorldSystem] Disabling WorldSystem v2.4.10 [14:57:23 ERROR]: Error occurred while disabling WorldSystem v2.4.10 (Is it up to date?)

So I think u might have imported an older Version of Spigot in your IDE so if you have try to import the same Spigot File as in your Server Directory

Comment: I updated the spigot file can tested it running into the same issue